# Excel MinIfs formula to return another value in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data in my spreadsheet

- Column A - date
- Column B - Time
- Column C - user
- Column D - Token Number
- Column E - Door
- Column F to I are not important

Column C contains the user names for all the door access tags

- In Column J I have the user names listed once
- In Column K I have the following formula: `=MINIFS(B:B,C:C,J2)`
  This looks up the first time a specific user entered through the door on that specific day.

I am trying to put the following data in column L - the door where the card was swiped.  I don't want to combine the data in column K and L.  I need the first swipe in column K (this formula is sorted and pulls the answer from column B) and then in column L I want to know what the corresponding door is (data in column E)

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BSWG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(MINIFS(B:B,C:C,J2),B:B,0))
```

The MATCH will return the relative row in B where the MINIFS return is found.  Then INDEX will return the value in E at that row.